# Find maximum for a function with two variables in the definition quantity

Tags: calculus

Hello fellow mathematicians,
I am trying to find maximum for the function:

```
f(x) =2xy^2 - 2x^2
```

In the following definition quantity:

```
x^2+y^2<=1, x>=0
```

It is obvious that the definition quantity is a half circle.
First I checked the stationary points, and I got the minimum (0,0)
Now I need to find maximum and I am sure it is on the edge, cuz I have not checked the edge yet. (not sure what you call this in English sorry, but on the edge of the definition quantity)

I think its obvious that the edge of the definition quantity is x^2+y^2 = 1. I've just removed the unequal sign and added in an equal sign.
But I don't know where to go from here. I want to find the maximum on the edge. Do I just put x=0 and x=1 and then solve for y? I'm not sure this is giving me the correct answer.

Kind regards,
Zebraboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on given constraints of $x \geq 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1, \, 0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq y \leq 1$.

Please observe that at $y = 1, x = 0$, So $2xy^2 - 2x^2 = 0$. Similarly at $x = 1, y = 0$, so $2xy^2 - 2x^2 = -2$.

Also for any value of $x$ in the range, maximum value of our function will be when we maximize $y$. That reasoning leads us to finding maximum at the circumference.

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers,

$2xy^2 - 2x^2 = \lambda (x^2 + y^2 - 1)$

Differentiating wrt. $x$ and $y$, we get

$2y^2 - 4x = 2 \lambda x \implies \lambda = \frac{2y^2 - 4x}{2x} \, $ (for $x \ne 0$)

$4xy = 2 \lambda y \implies \lambda = 2x \,$ (for $y \ne 0)$

Equating the two we get, $y^2 = 2(x^2 + x)$

Substituting in our constraint $x^2 + y^2 = 1, x^2 + \frac{2}{3}x = \frac{1}{3}$

i.e. $(x+ \frac{1}{3})^2 = \frac{4}{9} \implies x = \frac{1}{3}$

That gives us $y^2 =  \frac{8}{9}$.

We get maximum value of $2xy^2 - 2x^2 = \frac{10}{27}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! I don't really think I see how you get 2xy^2-2x^2=L(x^2+y^2-1)? Why -1?

Comment: @Zebraboard As per Lagrange Multiplier method, we are trying to find the maximum of function $f(x, y)$ subjected to the equality constraint $g(x, y) = 0$. We have to write in that form. From our equality constraint $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, we get $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$. As reasoned in the beginning, we are trying to find the maximum at the points on the circumference and hence the equality constraint.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I really appreciate your help!